# Render view Express after processing /POST

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'am trying to render a view after processing the file uploaded with Multer.
I got a error

> Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: res.redirect is not a function

What do i understand wrong ? 
Also the application never do the rendering on botom to 'step2.ejs'

```
app.post('/vision/upload', upload.single("upl"), function(req, res) {
var file = req.file;
filePath = req.file.path;
const req2 = new vision.Request({
    image: new vision.Image(file),
    features: [
        new vision.Feature('DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION', 10),
    ]
});
vision.annotate(req2).then((res) => {
    p1 = JSON.stringify(res.responses);
p1up = p1.toUpperCase();
occurrencesText = new Occurrences(p1up);
console.log(occurrencesText);
connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (var i in rows) {
        var occurence = stringOccurrence(p1up, rows[i].name);
        var fuzzy = fuzzysearch(rows[i].name, p1up);
        if(fuzzy = true){
            arrayResults.push([rows[i].name, occurence]);
        }
       //
    }
});
res.render('step2.ejs', {
    results: arrayResults,
    "filePath": filePath
});
```

})
});

Comment: Are you calling `res.redirect()` somewhere yourself?

Comment: Nope, the only otther res.render (not even redirec) i have is the home `route.app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    res.render('uploadform.ejs');
});`

Answer (score 0):

Rename `res` in `vision.annotate(req2).then((res) => {}))` as it is overriding the actual `res` object of the request.